# How to create a button to disable controls in a form, in LibreOffice Base 5.0.2.2

Tags: sql, button, macros, radix, libreoffice

Good day!

It's my first time using LibreOffice Base and I'm not very familiarized with the way Macros and SQL programming work in this tool.

What I want to do is to have either a push button or a check button that when pushed enables or disables a control or a series of controls. It seems to me that the simplest way would be to record a macro, but whenever I try to record it, it won't enable or disable the intended field. Instead, it merely goes into and out of design view.

However, I would prefer, if possible, to do this without having to resort to a macro. I believe the solution would have to be SQL, but I'm having a hard time understanding what syntax I would need to use to execute this procedure.

I'm not sure what other information you might require, but let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after much reading, I've been able to determine how to create a BASIC macro to allow for a check box to activate or deactivate a text control:

```
Sub enableID
   Dim  oDocument       As Object
   Dim  oForm           As Object
   Dim  oID             As Object
   Dim  oCheck          As Object

   oDocument      =  ThisComponent
   oForm          =  oDocument.getDrawPage().getForms().getByName("MainForm")
   oID            =  oForm.getByName("fmtID")
   oCheck         =  oForm.getByName("switchID")
   If oCheck.State    =  1 Then
      oID.Enabled    =  "True"
   Else
      oID.Enabled    =  "False"
   EndIf  
End Sub
```

However, I verified that the check box would clear once I switched to a different record. To stop this from happening I changed all my controls to a sub form except for thecheck box. However, I'm now for some reason being unable to select the SubForm in the macro, indicating that such an element doesn't exist. Here's the code for that:

```
Sub enableID
    Dim  oDocument       As Object
    Dim  oForm           As Object
    Dim  oFCheck         As Object
    Dim  oID             As Object
    Dim  oCheck          As Object

    oDocument      =  ThisComponent
    oForm          =  oDocument.getDrawPage().getForms().getByName("MainForm")
    oFCheck        =  oForm.getByName("subForm")
    oID            =  oFCheck.getByName("fmtID")
    oCheck         =  oForm.getByName("switchID")
    If oCheck.State    =  1 Then
        oID.Enabled    =  "True"
    Else
        oID.Enabled    =  "False"
    EndIf  
End Sub
```

I'm really at a stump here. I know I'm able to select the check box, and I've selected the MainForm before, so why can't I select the SubForm?

EDIT: The response for this problem was actually one of the most baffingly simple things I did not do: close the form and reopen it. It's now working. So, I guess I'm good :)